# How to delete recyclerview item with checkbox?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Problem: Clicking a checkbox only deletes the first item(cardview) which is at position[0] of the recyclerview. If I click another checkbox that has a different position, that item won't be deleted.

What I tried: I made an interface to listen for the click event handler. I got the adapter position and pass it to my click listener. I also tried using Lamba and try passing the click listener inside the adapter constructor.*

What I expected to happen: When a checkbox is clicked, the item(cardview) which has that position is deleted.

**Adapter Class**

```
 class ListAdapter(
    private val callback: AdapterCallBack

) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var todoList: List<TodoItem> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val context = parent.context
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_list, parent, false
        )
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todoList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = todoList[position]
        holder.itemView.tvTitle.text = currentItem.title
        holder.itemView.dueDate.text = currentItem.dueDate
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    fun setList(todo: List<TodoItem>) {
        this.todoList = todo
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(todoItem: TodoItem) {
            val position = adapterPosition

            itemView.setOnClickListener() {
                callback.onItemClick(todoItem, position)
            }
            itemView.doneCheckBox.setOnClickListener() {
                callback.onCheckBoxClick(todoItem, position)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Interface**

```
 interface AdapterCallBack {
 fun onCheckBoxClick(todoItem: TodoItem, position: Int)

 fun onItemClick(todoItem: TodoItem, position: Int)

}
```

**MainFragment(implements interface)**

```
    class MainFragment : Fragment(), AdapterCallBack {
            private lateinit var todoViewModel: TodoViewModel
            private lateinit var adapter : ListAdapter
            
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
            val recyclerView = view.recyclerview
           // checkDone  = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.doneCheckBox)
          adapter =
                ListAdapter(this)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            todoViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TodoViewModel::class.java)
            todoViewModel.getAllTodoItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                adapter.setList(it)
                Log.i("list", "$it")
            })
            view.fabBtn.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_detailFragment)
                (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.title = "Create"
                Log.i("fab_btn", "Fab button is pressed")
            }
    
            return view
        }
    
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_all, menu)
    
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        }
    
        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.delete_all_items -> {
                    todoViewModel.deleteAllItems()
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "All items deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return true
                }
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        }
        override fun onCheckBoxClick(todoItem: TodoItem, position: Int) {
            if (doneCheckBox.isChecked) {
                todoViewModel.deleteItem(todoItem)
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "Item deleted at position $position is click!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                Log.i("check_click", "$todoItem is deleted at position $position")
            }
        }
        override fun onItemClick(todoItem: TodoItem, position: Int) {
            val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailFragment(todoItem)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
            Log.i("cardview_click", "Card view  item $todoItem is click at position $position")
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel Class**

```
class TodoViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val getAllTodoItems: LiveData<List<TodoItem>>
    private val repository: TodoRepository
    private val selectedDate: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    private val selectedTime: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val date: LiveData<String>
        get() = selectedDate
    val time: LiveData<String>
        get() = selectedTime

    init {
        val todoDao = TodoDatabase.getDatabase(application).todoDao
        repository = TodoRepository(dao = todoDao)
        getAllTodoItems = repository.todoItems
    }

    fun insertItem(todoItem: TodoItem) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.insert(todoItem)
        }
    }
    fun updateItem(todoItem: TodoItem) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.update(todoItem)
        }

    }

    fun deleteItem(todoItem: TodoItem) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.delete(todoItem)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllItems() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteAll()

        }
    }

    fun setDateCalenderValue(date: String) {
        selectedDate.value = date
    }

    fun setTimePickerValue(time: String) {
        selectedTime.value = time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the adapter which row has been removed

Change your `onCheckBoxClick` function implementation to this

```
        override fun onCheckBoxClick(todoItem: TodoItem, position: Int) {
            if (doneCheckBox.isChecked) {
                todoViewModel.deleteItem(todoItem)
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) // Add this line
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "Item deleted at position $position is click!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                Log.i("check_click", "$todoItem is deleted at position $position")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this and the problem is still there. I believe the issue has to do with the checkbox click listener event but i'm not sure.

Comment: have you debugged this? make sure it hits the `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`

Comment: Ok I try debugging and found out that the ischeck is returning false for some reason. When I click the first item which is at position[0], the ischeck comes back as true and executes my command but if I click any other position, it comes back as false and so it won't execute my command.

Comment: hmm I think you should move `if (doneCheckBox.isChecked)` logic inside your adapter because your checkbox is associated to each row. Inside `itemView.doneCheckBox.setOnClickListener()`